# Pentaho in MAC M1

Tags: pentaho

I had installed pentaho in my MAC M1 but I don't know why today not load. I think is because I updated any version of JAVA. I downloaded a new version of Pentaho 9.3.0.0 and unzip and copy in applications. After that I replaced the file .jar and I can't not open.

This is the message from the terminal Rosetta

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Done! Several virtual machines in my library I keep temurin-8.jdk and works

Comment: Where did you find the file to install the pentaho? I tried the source gates but it didnt work